# Debug logging on Salesforce1 mobile app

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, debugging, javascript-remoting

Salesforce1 app has the option to send the app event log - however all this does is send a log reference key and not the log file itself.   Is it possible for developers to access this log or is it only available to Salesforce personnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Settings -> Advanced -> Send Event Logs
2. A mail window is displayed with the event log as an attachment.
3. Delete the filled-in recipient (iphonelogs@salesforce.com) and fill in your own.
4. Send!

I haven't seen the behavior you describe about a "log reference". My experience has been that the full log will be sent wherever you indicate.

Comment: I get a reference number but no attachment - is this an android only thing?

Comment: Steps above are from when I tried this on iOS. I haven't tried Android, sorry.