# How do i get logs for a lightning component loading in salesforce android app?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, iframe, android, debug-logs

I have added a lightening component to Salesforce, and its rendering fine in chrome on Salesforce and in Salesforce iOS app.
But, its not loading in Salesforce android app. and is showing blank.

Any pointers on how to debug that? How can i get console logs from Salesforce android app for a lightening component not loading?

Comment: hi, have you tried simulating it on Chrome ? As explained here : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quickstart-app-builder/quickstart-app-builder4 ?

Comment: Hi, yes. And it works fine in mobile chrome (in android). in salesforce.
But when i test it in sf android app, it doesnt work. and no errors.

Comment: Hi, I just bumped on this, but haven't tried: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46527/debug-logging-on-salesforce1-mobile-app
Did you have a look at that?